# viewPager page change for android MVVM

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, android-viewpager

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/onboard_next_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:onClick="@{vm::onButtonNext}"
        android:background="@color/customColor"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

I am implementing a viewpager page change logic on a button. Which is super easy if it was standard MVC. All I have to do is to write something like

```
 @Override
 public void onButtonNext(View view) {
    // viewPager does not exist in my onButtonNext function because this is the viewModel
   viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);
 }
```

because viewPager instance exists in my fragment or activity.

However, because I am implementing this in MVVM, I have no access to viewPager.  How do I implement a viewPager.setCurrentItem in my viewModel if I do not have access to viewPager instance?

Comment: Define some id to your ViewPager then you access it using your layout name databing instance like MyLayoutBinding.viewpager

Answer (score 1):

> However, because I am implementing this in MVVM, I have no access to
>   viewPager. How do I implement a viewPager.setCurrentItem in my
>   viewModel if I do not have access to viewPager instance?

you need a `public static void` method annotated with @BindingAdapter.

E.g.

```
  @BindingAdapter("currentItem")
  public static void setCurrentItem(ViewPager viewPager, int item) {
  }
```

and in the layout with will use something like `app:currentItem`. Of course your VM has to provide the `int` property or a getter for the item. Android takes care of the rest. You can read more about `BindingAdapter` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingAdapter.html)

Comment: Where should I define this `@BindingAdapter` method?

Comment: it is a static method. It doesn't really matter. In the past I had my `CustomBinding` utility class, where I put all my `@BindingAdapter` methods. you could do the same

Comment: I get the part about the 2nd argument - `int item`.

But this `@BindingAdapter("currentItem")` is attached to a `Button` view object in xml and not the `ViewPager` object in xml.  

So our `currentItem` binding adapter will still not have access to our `ViewPager` object

Comment: I see. This details was missing when you asked your question (Or I miss read it). What you could try is defining the property on the ViewPager, and using the delegate pattern to make the ViewModels communicate. But it is hard to give you an exact answer, without knowing the code